# Context property undefined in the child component when it is clearly there

Tags: reactjs

My main parent component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {Content} from './styles';

import {toast} from 'react-toastify';

import Steps from './Steps';

import PropertyInformation from './Information';
import Taxes from './Taxes';
import Sites from './Sites';
import Payment from './Payment';
import {SanctumContext} from "react-sanctum";

class Property extends Component {

    static contextType = SanctumContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            step: 1,
            completed: [],
            property: null
        };

        this.saveDraft = this.saveDraft.bind(this);
        this.nextStep = this.nextStep.bind(this);
    }

    saveDraft(data) {
        if (this.state.step == 1) {
            const draft = {
                pname: data.pname,
                image: data.image,
                email: data.email,
                website: data.website,
                fax: data.fax,
                phone: data.phone,
                checkin: data.checkin,
                checkout: data.checkout,
                address: data.address,
                country: data.country,
                state: data.state,
                city: data.city,
                latitude: data.latitude,
                longitude: data.longitude
            };
        }

        // call to save draft

        toast.success('Progress saved!')
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.match.params.id) {
            axios.get("/api/v1/getProperty/"+this.props.match.params.id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.context.propertyObject= response.data
                })
        }
    }

    nextStep(data) {
        if (this.state.step == 1) {
            const info = {
                pname: data.pname,
                image: data.image,
                email: data.email,
                website: data.website,
                fax: data.fax,
                phone: data.phone,
                checkin: data.checkin,
                checkout: data.checkout,
                address: data.address,
                country: data.country,
                state: data.state,
                city: data.city,
                latitude: data.latitude,
                longitude: data.longitude
            };
        }

        if (this.state.step == 2) {
            const taxes = data.taxes;
        }

        if (this.state.step == 4) {
            const info = {
                timeBefore: data.timeBefore,
                timeBeforeType: data.timeBeforeType,
                pets: data.pets,
                currency: data.currency,
                americanExpress: data.americanExpress,
                maestro: data.currency,
                visa: data.visa,
                discover: data.discover,
                euro: data.euro,
                unionPay: data.unionPay,
                diners: data.diners,
                jcb: data.jcb,
                invoiceName: data.invoiceName
            };
        }

        // call to save data
        const completed = this.state.completed;

        completed.push(this.state.step);

        this.setState({
            step: this.state.step + 1,
            completed: completed
        });

        toast.success('Progress saved!')
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Content>
                <Steps
                    step={this.state.step}
                    completed={this.state.completed}
                />

                {this.state.step == 1 &&
                    <PropertyInformation
                        saveDraft={(data) => this.saveDraft(data)}
                        nextStep={(data) => this.nextStep(data)}
                    />
                }

                {this.state.step == 2 &&
                    <Taxes
                        previous={() => this.setState({step: this.state.step - 1})}
                        saveDraft={(data) => this.saveDraft(data)}
                        nextStep={(data) => this.nextStep(data)}
                    />
                }

                {this.state.step == 3 &&
                    <Sites
                        previous={() => this.setState({step: this.state.step - 1})}
                        nextStep={() => this.setState({step: this.state.step + 1})}
                    />
                }

                {this.state.step == 4 &&
                    <Payment
                        previous={() => this.setState({step: this.state.step - 1})}
                        saveDraft={(data) => this.saveDraft(data)}
                        nextStep={(data) => this.nextStep(data)}
                    />
                }
            </Content>
        )
    }
}

export default Property;
```

And my PropertyInformation component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import InputMask from 'react-input-mask';
import Select from 'react-select';
import {FaCloudUploadAlt} from 'react-icons/fa'

import selectStyles from '../../../styles/selectInputStyles';

import {Content, Half, Form, ImageInput, ImagePreview, HalfInput, Controls, Span} from './styles';

import Location from './Location';
import {SanctumContext} from "react-sanctum";

class PropertyInformation extends Component {

    static contextType = SanctumContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            pname: null,
            image: null,
            imageURL: null,
            email: null,
            website: null,
            fax: null,
            phone: null,
            checkin: null,
            checkout: null,
            address: null,
            country: null,
            state: null,
            city: null,
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            countries: null
        }

        this.loadCountries = this.loadCountries.bind(this);
        this.updateImage = this.updateImage.bind(this);
        this.updateCountry = this.updateCountry.bind(this);
        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

    async loadCountries() {
        await axios.get("/api/v1/countries").then(response => {
            this.setState({countries: response.data});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            message("error", "Countries couldn't be loaded")
        })
    }

    updateImage(image) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        const url = reader.readAsDataURL(image);

        reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.setState({
                imageURL: [reader.result]
            })
        };
    }

    async updateCountry(selection) {
        await axios.get("/api/v1/states/"+selection.value).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                country: selection.value,
                states: response.data
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            message("error", "States couldn't be loaded")
        })
    }

    async updateState(selection) {
        await axios.get("/api/v1/cities/"+selection.value).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                state: selection.value,
                cities: response.data
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            message("error", "Cities couldn't be loaded")
        })
    }

    submit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const images = e.target.files
        let form = new FormData()
        form.append("image", images)
        axios.post("/api/v1/set-information", {
            user_id: this.context.user.id,
            name: this.state.pname,
            imageUrl: this.state.imageUrl,
            email: this.state.email,
            website: this.state.website,
            phone: this.state.phone,
            fax: this.state.fax,
            check_in: this.state.checkin,
            check_out: this.state.checkout,
            address: this.state.address,
            country: this.state.country,
            state: this.state.state,
            city: this.state.city,
            zip: this.state.zip,
            lat: this.state.latitude,
            long: this.state.longitude,
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                this.context.property = response.data.id
                this.props.nextStep(this.state);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if (err.response.status === 422) {
                message("error", err.response.message)
            }
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("OUT", this.context.propertyObject)
        if (this.context.propertyObject) {
            console.log("IN", this.context.propertyObject)
            /*console.log("ASDASDAasdassda")
            this.setState({phone: this.context.property.phone}, function(){
                console.log(this.state.phone)
            })*/
        }
        this.loadCountries();
    }

    render() {
        console.log("PHONE", this.state.phone)
        return(
            <Content>
                <Form>
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => this.submit(e)}>
                        <Half>
                            <p>Property Name*</p>
                            <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({pname: e.target.value})} required></input>

                            {!this.state.imageURL &&
                            <ImageInput>
                                <FaCloudUploadAlt />
                                <p>Upload main image</p>
                                <input type="file" value={this.state.image} onChange={e => this.updateImage(e.target.files[0])} />
                            </ImageInput>
                            }

                            {this.state.imageURL &&
                            <ImagePreview>
                                <img src={this.state.imageURL} />
                                <p onClick={() => this.setState({image: null, imageURL: null})}>Remove</p>
                            </ImagePreview>
                            }

                            <p>E-mail</p>
                            <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({email: e.target.value})}></input>

                            <p>Website</p>
                            <input
                                onChange={(e) => this.setState({website: e.target.value})}></input>

                            <section>
                                <HalfInput>
                                    <p>Phone number*</p>
                                    <InputMask
                                        onChange={(e) => this.setState({phone: e.target.value})}
                                        required
                                        mask="+999 99 999 99"
                                        alwaysShowMask
                                        maskChar="_"
                                    />
                                </HalfInput>
                                <HalfInput>
                                    <p>Fax</p>
                                    <InputMask
                                        onChange={(e) => this.setState({fax: e.target.value})}
                                        required
                                        mask="+999 99 999 99"
                                        alwaysShowMask
                                        maskChar="_"
                                    />
                                </HalfInput>
                            </section>

                            <section>
                                <HalfInput>
                                    <p>Check-in*</p>
                                    <InputMask
                                        onChange={(e) => this.setState({checkin: e.target.value})}
                                        required
                                        mask="99:99"
                                        alwaysShowMask
                                        maskChar="_"
                                    />
                                </HalfInput>

                                <HalfInput>
                                    <p>Check-out*</p>
                                    <InputMask
                                        onChange={(e) => this.setState({checkout: e.target.value})}
                                        required
                                        mask="99:99"
                                        alwaysShowMask
                                        maskChar="_"
                                    />
                                </HalfInput>
                            </section>
                        </Half>
                        <Half>
                            <p>Address*</p>
                            <input onChange={e => this.setState({address: e.value})} required></input>

                            <section>
                                <HalfInput>
                                    <p>Country*</p>
                                    <Select
                                        options={this.state.countries}
                                        styles={selectStyles}
                                        onChange={e => this.updateCountry(e)}
                                        placeholder=''
                                    />
                                </HalfInput>

                                <HalfInput>
                                    <p>State*</p>
                                    <Select
                                        options={this.state.states}
                                        styles={selectStyles}
                                        onChange={e => this.updateState(e)}
                                        placeholder=''
                                    />
                                </HalfInput>
                            </section>

                            <section>
                                <HalfInput>
                                    <p>City*</p>
                                    <Select
                                        options={this.state.cities}
                                        styles={selectStyles}
                                        onChange={e => this.setState({city: e.value})}
                                        placeholder=''
                                    />
                                </HalfInput>

                                <HalfInput>
                                    <p>Zip*</p>
                                    <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({zip: e.target.value})} required></input>
                                </HalfInput>
                            </section>

                            <section>
                                <HalfInput>
                                    <p>Latitude</p>
                                    <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({latitude: e.target.value})}></input>
                                </HalfInput>

                                <HalfInput>
                                    <p>Longitude</p>
                                    <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({longitude: e.target.value})}></input>
                                </HalfInput>
                            </section>

                            <Location
                                address={`${this.state.country}, ${this.state.state}, ${this.state.city}, `}
                            />

                            <Controls>
                                <Span disabled>Previous</Span>
                                <Span onClick={() => this.props.saveDraft(this.state)}>Save as draft</Span>

                                <button>Proceed</button>
                            </Controls>
                        </Half>
                    </form>
                </Form>
            </Content>
        )
    }
}

export default PropertyInformation;
```

There is a property in the context `propertyObject`, which is set in the parent component. Consoling log the `contenxt` in the child shows that `propertyObject` is there and loaded with data. But if I try to reach I get `undefined`. `this.context.propertyObject`

Comment: Tomav, in which function call do you get `undefined` when accessing `this.context.propertyObject`?

Comment: `componentDidMount` and `constructor`. I tried in both.

Comment: `console.log(this.context)` returns correct object. `        console.log(this.context.propertyObject)` returns undefined when it is there in the first log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to directly modify a context object inside a consumer. This isn't going to work. You need to modify the context value at the point that it is Provided to the React application.

As a rule, context consumers shall not mutate or modify a context value.

Now, I am unfamiliar with react-sanctum, but after briefly reviewing the documentation, it does not apepar that you are given access to the context provider.

You will need to find a different way to pass propertyObject down to your child component. Either pass by props, or create a new context and render a Context.Provider above your child component.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype

Comment: The same happens if i send it as property. `this.props.property.phone`  is null but `this.props.property` has phone field in it and it is not empty.